# Sending email with attachment from android app used to work, now does not, no idea what changed

Tags: android, email

I have a 2+ year old app that I just made some minor changes to and I seem to have broken the ability to send emails with file attachments from the app, which used to work... here is the code, it hasn't changed...

```
File path = new File(G.FilePath + "/" + ContextMenuFileName);
String subject = D.OTDRNAME + " OTDR Trace File: \"" + ContextMenuFileName + "\"";
String message = "This e-mail was sent from the " + D.APPNAME + " Android application.";
Uri URI = Uri.parse("file://" + path.getPath());

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);             
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Select E-Mail Application"));
return true;
```

When using the app it will ask me for the app to use to send the email (per the Intent.createChooser() call) and I choose gmail and then the gmail app starts up with the subject and body of the message filled in and with a symbol showing the file attachment... so the gmail app is showing the file attachment... yet no matter where I send the email to the attached file never shows up on the receiving end.

Here is a screenshot of the emailIntent details showing the URI string in use just before calling startActivity()

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6daP.png

Comment: 'G.FilePath'. You think we know what's in there?

Comment: The problem is that you serve your file from private intern memory unaccessable for other apps.

Comment: 'showing the URI string'. Please do. Or tell.

Comment: greenapps: I edited it to show a screenshot of the intent details just before the call to startactivity, it shows the URI string.

You know what? I think the location of the file did change... it used to be on the SD card I believe. So that's the problem then, the gmail app can't access the file?

Comment: Please take the effort to just tell this important information in your post.

Comment: You mean you don't want to click the link to see the screenshot? The URI was: "file://data/data/com.companynamehere.appnamehere/files/filenamehere.sor"

Comment: But what is the value of URI.getPath()? There should not be 'file://' in it to begin with. But anyhow that is private memory which is unreachable for other apps.

Comment: I'm going to try copying the file to the SD card first, if that works I'll let you know and you can submit it as an answer and I'll approve it. Thanks

Comment: That worked, thanks, if you want add it as the answer and I'll accept it, if you get points for it or whatever

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you serve your file from private intern memory unaccessable for other apps.

You could leave it there and make it 'world readable' but that is an old technic. Better serve the file with a FileProvider.